# How to solve this quadratic equation?

Tags: quadratics

> Question: 
>   Given that $r$ is a root of the quadratic equation $x^2−3x−5=0$, find the value of $2r^2−6r+1$

Thx a lot, because I can't see the pattern of this quadratic equation, so I am struggling a lot to use $r={3±√29\over 2}$ in $2r^2−6r+1$

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint, what's the value of $2r^2-6r-10$?

Comment: So what is your thinking, and what have you tried? What do you know about $r$ which might help you to evaluate the target expression?

Comment: Hint: If $r$ is a root of the equation then $r$ will satisfy the equation !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2-3x=5$$

$r$ is the value that makes that ^ equation correct. So:

$$r^2-3r=5$$

$$2r^2-6r=10$$

$$2r^2-6r+1=11$$

Answer (score 4):

One way is to literally find $r$, which isn't too hard since $x^2-3x-5=0$ has roots $x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{29}}{2}$.

The way they probably want you to solve this question is to recognize that $r$ satisfies $r^2-3r-5=0$. Multiplying by $2$ yields $2r^2-6r-10=0$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $2x^2 - 6x = 2(x^2-3x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't see the pattern, you can always use the relation
$$r^2 - 3r - 5=0$$
to replace $r^2$ by $3r+5$ in the expression you want to evaluate.

In the worst case, since the expression to be evaluated is a quadratic polynomial in $r$, if $r$ doesn't get caneceled in the simplification, you'll end up with a linear expression instead of a quadratic one, so it's still a good strategy.

Thus,
\begin{align*}
r^2-3r - 5 &= 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;r^2 &= 3r +5\\[4pt]
\implies\;2r^2-6r+1&=2(3r+5)-6r+1\\[4pt]
&=(6r+10)-6r +1\\[4pt]
&=11\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

But here's an observation . . .

Let's say at the outset, you were considering using the quadratic formula to solve for $r$. But the coefficients are real and the discriminant is
$$b^2 - 4ac = (-3)^2-4(1)(-5) = 29$$
so even without solving, you know the equation has two *distinct* real roots.

But now, if you change your mind about using the quadratic formula, switching instead to the approach where you replace $r^2$ by $3r+5$, then even before making the substitution, it's clear that the result will simplify to either a constant or a polynomial of degree $1$ in $r$.

But if you assume that the answer is *unique*, then, since the problem didn't specify *which* root $r$, the expression can't end up being degree $1$ in $r$. That's because a polynomial of degree $1$ can't realize the same value twice, so must yield a different result for each root, contrary to the assumption of uniqueness.

The upshot of this observation is that you *expect* that in the process of simplification, the $r$ terms will cancel.

That said, you still have to do the work for the evaluation, but when the $r$ terms *do* cancel, then, based on this thought process, it shouldn't come as a surprise.